# Typescript: Cannot import class from module

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a `ViewModel` written in `Typescript` and I wrote some unit tests for it with `jasmine`. The problem is that I cannot import the class from its module. I have tried many different ways to import the class but with no success.

```
export module App.Employee.Leader {
    export class LeaderViewModel {

        public elements: number;

        constructor(leaderElements : number)
        {
            var self = this;
            self.elements = leaderElements;
        }

        calculateHeight(numElements: number)
        {
            var self = this;
            var leaderElements = self.elements;

            if (numElements > leaderElements)
                return numElements + "px";
            else
                return self.elements + "px";
        }
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

import Module = require("Areas/Employee/Scripts/App/Leader/LeaderViewModel");
import LeaderViewModel = Module.App.Employee.Leader.LeaderViewModel;

describe("calculateHeight", () => {
    it("calculate height accordingly", () =>
    {
        var leaderViewModel = new LeaderViewModel(10);

        var result = leaderViewModel.calculateHeight(20);

        expect(result).toEqual("20px");
    });
});
```

This is the error I get:

> Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules.
>   Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"',
>   'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

I have tried fixing it the way it suggests but to no avail.

How can I import the class from the module in my spec files?

Do I have to set some setting in `tsconfig.json`?

Please offer detailed explanation because I am new to Typescript.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about just using `import {LeaderViewMode} from 'path/to/your/module/file`?

Comment: Tried this already, didn't work, same error.

Comment: Most probable case is wrong setup of compilerOptions.module in tsconfig. Could you please share how your toolchain looks like? Do you use karma-typescript or webpack or babel or some ngTools? Which TS/browser versions? Etc...